# Compare if the characters in a string are a subset of a second string in C#

Tags: c#, linq, string-comparison

I'm working on a game where I want to check if the characters of a string are contained in another string. Obviously a set would be my first choice but I want to account for duplicates. For example:

```
"met".IsContainedWithin("meet"); => true
"meet".IsContainedWithin("met"); => false
```

A multi-set would be nice but it sounds like C# doesn't have anything like that. I could just do it iteratively but I was wondering if there was a simpler way (with LINQ perhaps). Thanks!

EDIT:

I wasn't so clear. I want it to return true regardless of the order of the letters:

```
 "git".IsContainedWithin("light")=> true
 "pall".IsContainedWithin("lamp")=> false
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: I tried putting it into a set and I tried unioning them and then checking if the count was the same but that didn't account for duplicates

Comment: What are the rules for being a subset? Because I don't see how "met" is a subset of "meet".

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov not a proper subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static bool IsContainedWithin(this string @this, string container)
{
    var lookup = container.ToLookup(c => c);
    return @this.ToLookup(c => c).All(c => lookup[c.Key].Count() >= c.Count());
}
```

I tested it like this:

```
var tests = new []
{
    "met".IsContainedWithin("meet"),
    "meet".IsContainedWithin("met"),
    "git".IsContainedWithin("light"),
    "pall".IsContainedWithin("lamp"),
};
```

I got these results:

```
True 
False 
True 
False
```